# Do all garbage disposal units adhere to the same plumbing connection standards?

Tags: garbage-disposal

I need to replace a dead, 11-year-old garbage disposal unit.  Before I go shopping for a new one, I'd like to confirm that any new product from a mainstream USA brand will conform to the same plumbing connection standards (width of pipe, etc.).

I haven't been able to infer the answer to this question on any of the DIY websites, so I thought I would ask here.